# Export table to CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, blob, export-to-csv

Im trying to export and save table content to CSV, and Its working, but I want to hide/remove a specifik div before the export save.
I want to hide/remove span.delete-list-domains, before I export/save my table to CSV.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
    //$("span.delete-list-domains").hide();
    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),
    tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
    tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0),
    colDelim = '","',
    rowDelim = '"\r\n"',
    csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
            $cols = $row.find('td');

        return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
            var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();
            return text.replace(/"/g, '""');
        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

    }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
        .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
        .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

        // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
            type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
        });

        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {       
        var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8' });
        var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        $(this)
            .attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href': csvUrl
            });
    } else {
        var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
        $(this)
            .attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
            });
    }
}

$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];    
    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);
});});
```

Comment: Where is the error? you commented the line which will hide the div already..

Comment: Hi! This line is not working $("span.delete-list-domains").hide();

Comment: is the export working ?
Are you sure about the class name of this span?
try $(".delete-list-domains").hide();
Try to declare the function before jQuery(document).ready and just call it there

Comment: The export is working, and the class is right.

Comment: I tried to declare the function before jQuery(document).ready and just call it there, but is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Its working now, when Im using remove() and not hide :).

Comment: Can you post the fix using remove()? I am trying to do something similar and not show text in a column that is wrapped in a specific span tag class on export.

Comment: Hi! Instead of using hide(); use remove(); :)